# Views Ticker missing views, what are views and where can I get them

Tags: views

I have just installed the module called "views ticker" but I cannot activate it as apparently it requires : views(missing).

Today represents my first experiments in Drupal (I am using V7), so I'm finding some things a little less straightforward than I would expect. For this reason I'm a little lost here, I don't know what "views" are being referred to here much less do I know how to give the module the "views" it requires!

So, any pointers in the right direction would be appreciated.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modules sometimes have dependencies on other modules.

The [Views module](http://drupal.org/project/views) is one of the most used modules in all of Drupal that isn't a part of Drupal core.

Generally you can find your missing modules by going to `http://drupal.org/project/[name]`. This is not always true as some modules is not a single module but multiple modules. Views is one of those modules, that has a core module called Views, and an UI module called Views UI which is used to create the interface for setting up views.

Comment: Thanks for the straightforward answer - problem solved :)